# Moving progress bar not to show percentage in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I am currently developing a C# application using WPF. This is going to be difficult to explain but I'll give it a go.

What I want to be able to do is to have a progress bar. The progress bar is not going to show a percentage of the progress completed instead it is just supposed to keep moving the bar from left to right in a loop, like what windows does when it is calculating how long it is going to take when transferring a large sized file before it actually does the copy.

How can I do this instead of showing a normal progress bar.

Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Hopefully you might find this link helpful : [WPF Circular Progress Indicator : How To...](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/4d89b4cb-ba59-4362-ab0a-cc047643fd42/wpf-circular-progress-indicator.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

[ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.isindeterminate.aspx)

```
ProgressBar p = new ProgressBar();
p.IsIndeterminate = true;
```